# MySQL Query to Determine Overlapping Timestamps - Schedule System

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table that stores shift records for employees.

Simply, there's the following data:

```
id = Shift ID
employeenum = Employee Number
start = unix timestamp of shift start time
end = unix timestamp of shift end time
date = YYYY-mm-dd description of date the shift starts on
status = shift status (numeric status identifier)
```

I am currently determining conflicts through a looping php script but it's far too slow. I've searched other questions and can't quite find the answer I'm looking for.

I am trying to come up with a query that will basically give me a list of employeenums that have conflicting shifts within a given time period.

i.e. for the period 2016-07-03 to 2016-07-10, which employees have overlapping start and end timestamps for shifts with a status value of 1 or 7.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

EDIT

[This](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43d5d) is essentially the table structure.

id is a primary auto increment key. The table is full of numeric data.

ID is an autoincremented number, employeenum is a 6 digit number, start and end are unix timetamps, date is YYYY-mm-dd date format, overridden is 1 or 0, status is 1,2,3,4,5,6, or 7.

Current loop works by querying:

```
SELECT *  FROM schedule WHERE overridden =0 AND date >=$startdate AND date <= $enddate AND (status = 1 OR status = 7)  AND employeenum != 0 ORDER BY date ASC
```

It then loops through all of those returned shifts to test whether or not another one conflicts with them by executing this query over and over (using the returned `start` and `end` values from the results of the above query):

```
SELECT `employeenum` FROM `schedule` WHERE `overridden` =0 AND `date` >= '$startdate' AND `date` <= '$enddate' AND (`status` = '1' OR `status` = '7') AND ((('$start' > `start`) AND ('$start' < `end`)) OR ((`end` > '$start') AND (`end` < '$end'))) AND `employeenum` = '$employee';"
```

If there is a result, it pushes the employee number to an array of employees with conflicts. This then prevents the loop from checking for that employee again.

At any given time there could be 10,000 records, so it's executing 10,000+ queries. These records represent only 100-200 employees, so I am looking for a way to query one time to see if there are any overlapping (`start` and `end` overlap with another `start` or `end`) records between two `date` values for one `employeenum` without having to query the database 10,000 times.

Comment: lets see your php code!

Comment: Basically it follows this logic:
Select records that are in the time period.
Loop through records, if employee number is not in conflict array, check to see if conflicts exist.
If a conflict exists, push the employee number to conflict array.
Move to next record.

The problem is it's just way too slow and is querying over and over every single time. I would like to solve this with one query if possible.

Comment: sorry explanations aren't going to cut it here, include your code and we can help

Comment: Thank you and I appreciate your intentions, however as I stated, I am looking for a query solution, not a revision to the PHP code. The hosting package the client is using is not capable of doing the iterative repetitive queries  which is why I am trying to accomplish it with 1 query per employee. I am looking for help building a query.

Comment: okay well you need to include your original query then, you should also update your data structure, ie is `id` your primary auto increment key -or- is it a foreign key that links to a shift table ... give some example data or paste stuff here http://sqlfiddle.com/ and provide a link

Comment: Thanks - see edit above.

Comment: Can the overlap occur only when the date is the same? right now in your second query, say there was a shift Monday from 7-11 and Tuesday there was a shift from 8-12 it would consider this as a conflict ... but is it?  You can paste more into that fiddle including insert commands to help fill out the data and make it easier to understand.

Comment: Sqlfiddle link updated. Answer to your Q: it would not consider it a conflict because the `start` and `end` columns are unix timestamps. The `date` column is used as a quick reference without calculating the timestamp range. Example: Employee A has a shift on Tuesday that starts at timestamp 1000000 and ends at 1000999, and another one that starts at 1000990 and ends at 1001000, that would be a conflict. The date field isn't really necessary in this context other than I currently use it to limit the period the conflicts are being checked for without having to calculate the unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted from  @cmorrissey 's answer. THANK YOU!!

```
SELECT `schedule_test`.`id`, `schedule_test`.`date`, 
`schedule_test`.`employeenum`,     
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT`join_tbl`.`employeenum`),  
COUNT(`join_tbl`.`employeenum`)

FROM `schedule_test` 
INNER JOIN `schedule_test` AS `join_tbl` ON 
`schedule_test`.`date` = `join_tbl`.`date` 
AND (`join_tbl`.`status` = 1 OR `join_tbl`.`status` = 7)
AND (`join_tbl`.`employeenum` = `schedule_test`.`employeenum`) 
AND (`join_tbl`.`start` BETWEEN `schedule_test`.`start` AND `schedule_test`.`end` 
    OR `join_tbl`.`end` BETWEEN `schedule_test`.`start` AND `schedule_test`.`end`) 
AND `schedule_test`.`id` != `join_tbl`.`id` 
WHERE (`schedule_test`.`status` = 1 OR `schedule_test`.`status` = 7) 
GROUP BY `schedule_test`.`id`
ORDER BY `schedule_test`.`date`
```

Answer (score 0):

This Query will give you the shift id, the date, the employee number, the conflicting employee numbers and a count of conflicting shifts. You have a ton of shifts that conflict in your dataset!!!

```
SELECT `schedule_test`.`id`, `schedule_test`.`date`, `schedule_test`.`employeenum`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT`join_tbl`.`employeenum`), COUNT(`join_tbl`.`employeenum`)
FROM `schedule_test` 
INNER JOIN `schedule_test` AS `join_tbl` ON 
    `schedule_test`.`date` = `join_tbl`.`date` 
    AND (`join_tbl`.`status` = 1 OR `join_tbl`.`status` = 7) 
    AND (`join_tbl`.`start` BETWEEN `schedule_test`.`start` AND `schedule_test`.`end` 
        OR `join_tbl`.`end` BETWEEN `schedule_test`.`start` AND `schedule_test`.`end`) 
    AND `schedule_test`.`id` != `join_tbl`.`id` 
WHERE (`schedule_test`.`status` = 1 OR `schedule_test`.`status` = 7) 
GROUP BY `schedule_test`.`id`
ORDER BY `schedule_test`.`date`
```

Comment: Hmm very close, but it returns all the employeenums in the dataset whether or not they conflict. I've included a larger dataset here (largest sqlfiddle will allow me to do). I like this direction though, very creative. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/788762

Comment: @benp its working correctly you just have that many shifts that overlap, if you have one shift that overlaps 27 people you have 27 conflicts.  And you will get a list of each of their names. I have updated my answer to provide more detail.

Comment: Sorry I think you have misunderstood what i consider to be a conflict. If employee A is scheduled at the same time twice, that's a conflict. If employee A and B are scheduled at the same time, that's not a conflict. However, very easy fix. Thank you very much for your help, I wouldn't have figured this out without your assistance.